# How to Detect Change in a Text Input Box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html-input

I have two text input text box and I want to do the total of whatever no entered by the user. Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(".test").on("input", function(){
        // Print entered value in a div box
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
        $("#result").text( total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput"></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput"></p>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

When I input `10` first then it takes `11`, then if I enter 100 then it takes `111`, I am no getting why this happening. Where I am making an error, guide me?

Comment: It's because you're adding the value for every *character* that's typed. Eg. if you type `10`, it adds `0 + 1` for the first character, then `1 + 10`.

Comment: then what will be correct solution for this ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Try the `change` event instead

Comment: try my answer with the `change` event. @MohammedSabir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't showed you the result you want to, is because the calculation is wrong. You now add the number to the total, every time one input field changes. So if you type 123, it takes 0 + 1 , then 1 + 12, then 13 + 123 so you'll have 136 as result.

I wrote a possible solution for your question. The code is in the fiddle below.

You could add a function where you calculate the total of all input fields (may be more than 2, it's generic).

```
function calculateTotal(){
  var total = 0;
    $(".test").each(function( index ) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      if(value == ""){
        return;
      }
      total += parseInt(value);

    });
  $("#result").text(total);
}
```

And on the change of your input fields, you just execute that function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".test").on("input", function(){
        calculateTotal();
    });
});
```

Your example is in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xL6hgder/2/

Answer (score 3):

On your code when you enter the first digit it's been calculated to the total because of your code `total += parseInt($(this).val())`. for example, if your press first digit as 1 then at that time total is updating as `total = total + 1` which equals 1, on the second keypress, for example, take 0, then your input value becomes 10. it is calculating to the current total value as `total = total + 10`. that's why you are getting 11 as answer

Try like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".test").on("input", function(){
    let total = 0;
    $('.test').each(function() {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $("#result").text(total);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput1"></p>
<p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput2"></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Please explain *why* you think this is the solution instead of just some code, so that OP can understand and solve it themself next time :)

Comment: You can't just hardcoded the input select method suppose if there are more than two input fields then your code condition will be going to modified again and again. Try my answer as well or you can update your answer. @Yahiya

Comment: you are right @ShubhamBaranwal. But on his question, he said he has two text fields, no mention of the dynamic amount of fields that why I added the answer like this. Also, a thumbs up for your answer too... ;)

Comment: True, but your answer does not only help this user, but your answer can also help others too if it's optimized and scalable for others. @Yahiya

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal acknowledged

Answer (score 1):

You just update total with that input value that you're trying to change.

For getting the total for both input values you have to take both values and add it with the total.

Try below code-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").on("change", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.test').each(function() {
      if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
      }
    });
    // Print entered value in a div box

    $("#result").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput"></p>
<p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput"></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".test").on('input', function () {
            var total = parseInt($("#result").text());
            total = parseInt($("#myInput").val()) + parseInt($("#myInput1").val());
            $("#result").text(total);
        });
    });

 <p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="test" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput1" /></p>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the change event instead of the input event. It will only fire when the value is "commited", instead of every keystroke. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) for details.

Comment: You should write this into comment section, not as an answer.